# my android project is working fine, I didn't changed any code but when I compiled my app again and again an error occurs in apothems jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

there is error in my kt file
error 1: /classroom/ClassroomFragment.kt:41:42 Unresolved reference: AppTheme
error 2: /classroom/ClassroomFragment.kt:81:13 Unresolved reference: AppTheme
error 3: /classroom/ClassroomFragment.kt:82:17 @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

I am adding ////////////////////////// in which error is occurring

```
@file:OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)

package com.sturec.sturecteacher.ui.dashboard.classroom

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.compose.foundation.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyRow
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Add
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Close
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Delete
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Done
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Refresh
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList
import androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateMap
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.alpha
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.modifier.modifierLocalConsumer
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewCompositionStrategy
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.Dimension
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.sturec.sturecteacher.R
import com.sturec.sturecteacher.data.classroom_operations.*
import com.sturec.sturecteacher.databinding.FragmentClassroomBinding

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import com.sturec.sturecteacher.ui.theme.AppTheme
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import com.sturec.sturecteacher.util.UiEvents
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@AndroidEntryPoint
class ClassroomFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentClassroomBinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ClassroomViewModel::class.java]

        _binding = FragmentClassroomBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root = binding.root

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.uiEvent.collect { event ->
                when (event) {
                    is UiEvents.ShowSnackbar -> {
                        Snackbar.make(
                            binding.root,
                            event.message,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                    else->{

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        binding.classroomComposeView.apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                AppTheme(useDarkTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                    ClassroomFragmentContent(viewModel) // Call the Composable function here
                }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
        }

        return root
    }

}
@Composable
fun ClassroomFragmentContent(viewModel: ClassroomViewModel) {
    ClassroomFragmentUi(viewModel)
}
```

I want to solve this error, my code is working fine after some compilations it started to throw an error